# String separated by spaces to object in javascript

Tags: javascript

From a string which looks like:

"Apple Banana 26"

or

"Dog Likes Food"

How would one get objects such as:

Apple={Banana:"26"}

Dog={Likes:"Food"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want an object not a variables from strings (which gets ugly) you can simply [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)

```js
let str = "Dog Likes Food"

let obj = str.split(' ').reduceRight((obj, word) => ({[word]: obj}))
console.log(obj)
```

This has the added benefit that it doesn't care how many words you have:

```js
let str = "Dog Likes To Eat Dog Food"

let obj = str.split(' ').reduceRight((obj, word) => ({[word]: obj}))
console.log(obj)
```

If you are determined to get the variable `Dog` you can use `Object.assign` to merge the object with the `window` object creating a global. But there's almost always a better approach than creating globals:

```js
let str = "Dog Likes Food"

let obj = str.split(' ').reduceRight((obj, word) => ({[word]: obj}))
Object.assign(window, obj)

console.log(Dog)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the 3-words string to a JSON object, I show you the idea in the next example:

```js
var string1 = "Apple Banana 26";
var string2 = "Dog Likes Food";

// Convert 3 words string to a JSON object.

function strToObj(str)
{
   var items = str.split(' ');
   
   if (items.length != 3)
       return false;

   var jsonStr = '{"' + items[0] + '":' +
                 '{"' + items[1] + '":"' +
                 items[2] + '"}}';

   return JSON.parse(jsonStr);
}

// Test the method.

var apple = strToObj(string1);

if (apple)
    console.log(apple);
else
   console.log("Fail to convert!");
   
var dog = strToObj(string2);

if (dog)
    console.log(dog);
else
   console.log("Fail to convert!");
```